# Geodesic symmetry of a locally symmetric space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, arithmetic-groups

Let $M = \Gamma \backslash G/K$ be a Riemannian locally symmetric space, where $G$ is a connected semisimple Lie group of rank at least $2$, $K$ its maximal compact subgroup and $\Gamma < G$ an irreducible lattice.

**Question:** Does $M$ admit a global geodesic symmetry?

By a geodesic symmetry I mean an isometry of $M$ fixing a point $x\in M$ and reversing all geodesics through $x$. If the answer is NO then are there related general results?

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is a maximal arithmetic subgroup then the answer is NO. Indeed, the symmetry (or any isometry of $M$) belongs to the normalizer of $\Gamma$ in $G$ but then (by the maximality) belongs to $\Gamma$. But the $\Gamma$ action is free so the symmetry can not belong to $\Gamma$.

Comment: @Holonomia: There is no reason for $\Gamma$ to be torsion-free. In fact, if $\Gamma_0$ is a lattice  with torsion, every maximal lattice $\Gamma$ containing $\Gamma_0$ will again contain torsion.

Comment: @MoisheCohen : if  $M$ is a manifold then the action of the latice must be free, isnt'it?

Comment: @Holonomia: Sure, but why would a maximal arithmetic lattice yield a manifold? (It does not, in general.) I know that in rank 1 there are maximal lattices which are torsion-free, but I do not know why this would be the case in higher rank.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen: the OP question assume $M$ to be a manifold, actually a locally symmetric space, isnt'it?

Comment: @Holonomia: Not for everybody; it is quite common to allow orbifolds as  locally symmetric spaces. But even if OP asked about manifolds, maximal lattices are only relevant if there are such which are torsion-free.

Comment: @MoisheCohen the OP wrote explicitelly Riemannian locally symmetric space and for such it is not quite common to allow orbifolds as you said. As for the relevance of my comment must be the the OP to decide so.

Comment: @Holonomia and MoisheCohen: Thank you for your comments. I am vague on M being a manifold and I understand that the answer is NO in general. Examples I have in mind are: a hyperelliptic involution of a surface, a Cartan involution preserving a lattice, e.g., inverse transpose on $SL(n,\mathbf R)$ preserving $SL(n,\mathbf Z)$ (here we have an orbifold but by taking an appropriate finite index subgroup we can make a manifold example) and other arithmetic examples. In general, every Cartan involution preserves some lattice (I learned this from TN Venkataramana).